# How to open android keyboard in a tabhost on click edititext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tabhost

I am developing an android app. An activity has a tabhost with 5 tabs. The second tab has a edittext widget. When I press on that I want keyboard to show up. How to get the focus to edittext widget from tabhost?[image]

Here's my java code:

```
public class activities extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
ImageView imageView;
Button btnCapturePicture;
File file;
static int count=0;
String imgPath,selectedImagePath;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activities);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);

    TabHost th=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    th.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.camera);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.chat);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat15));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.profile);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_blue));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag4");
    specs.setContent(R.id.history);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.history2));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag5");
    specs.setContent(R.id.settings);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings5));
    th.addTab(specs);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview6);
    btnCapturePicture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Try to use this code.

If you want close the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method to show keyboard on click

```
public static void openKeyBoard(View textView) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Env.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> First you need to get `onClick` of `Tab 2` And `onClick` you can open `KeyBoard`.

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG,"1"+getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag());

            editText.requestFocus();
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am getting an error. cannot resolve method gettabhost() if activities class extends appcompatactivity. but if tabactivity is extended gettabhost() shows no error. but R.id.tabhost shows an error message.